# Tuple vs array in SQL

Tags: sql, database

This is a very basic question, but I'm wondering if someone could explain the difference to me of what I would think is a tuple and an array in SQL. As a basic example:

```
SELECT 
    [1,2], -- array
    "us" in ("us", "ca") -- tuple
```

Why for example, does `1 in [1,2]` not work but `1 in (1,2)` does? Is a 'tuple' the correct understanding of what `("us", "ca")` is, or is that a row type?

As a reference, in python I can often treat a list and tuple the same (though it's a dynamic language):

```
>>> 1 in [1,2]
True
>>> 1 in (1,2)
True
```

So I'm just seeing if I can understand the differences between the two in SQL and how they are formally defined.

A few more examples:

```
-- UNNEST
SELECT country 
FROM unnest(['us', 'ca', 'fr']) as country -- OK
WHERE country in unnest(['ca', 'fr'])      -- OK

-- TUPLE
SELECT country 
FROM ('us', 'ca', 'fr') as country         -- ERROR
WHERE country in ('ca', 'fr')              -- OK

-- LIST
SELECT country 
FROM ['us', 'ca', 'fr'] as country         -- ERROR
WHERE country in ['ca', 'fr']              -- ERROR
```

Perhaps related:

- Row type in DB2: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=erdtu-example-row-data-type-use-in-sql-function
- Row type in Oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/rowtype_attribute.htm

Comment: What kind of database / sql language is this?

Comment: @topsail -- this is more conceptual so database doesn't matter, but I'm using Postgres, BigQuery, MySQL and a few others for testing / entering in statements to play around with

Comment: To be clear, you don't mind if none of this works in real databases?

Comment: @topsail sure that's fine.

Comment: you need to ask the developer of a database, why they implemented a feature and another not, basis of all databases is standared sql, afaik there no arrays or lists in standard sql, so nobody can answer why

Comment: tuples are more traditionally the name of database row structures. Internally, in most databases they are stored as leaves of trees. It makes sense to return a tuple as a representation of a database row because they are fixed in size (number of elements) and cannot be resized with destroying the tuple - it is an N-Tuple. But in practice, I would imagine you could as easily treat a row of data as a list as you could a tuple. In some cases, tuples can have named elements, so that would be an advantage there. But as with nbk - none of this really part standard SQL.